# Harry Potter fanfiction where he's abandoned in an orphanage

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, slytherin

I remember that Harry has long hair and he has a different name like Indy or something. Someone gave him his name by translating ''lightning'' (I think) in Hindi, but when I research it I can't find anything.

He was raised in an orphanage, where he was abused and neglected. When he goes into Hogwarts, he is sorted in Slytherin. He is really powerful and decides to go with Tom Riddle. He is friends with Snape and Malfoy.

I read this story a maximum of one year ago on Wattpad, but I don't know where to find it. It's like it disappeared.

Ps: I'm French. Sorry for the mistakes and thanks for the edits. :)

Comment: A better question is, was the huge potato *ever really gone*?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fan-fiction-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. In particular, where did you read this story (and when)? Do you recall which other characters were in it? Can you remember any specific phrases from the story?

Comment: Was Indy short for Indigo? (e.g. "Indigo ‘Indy’ Potter")?

Comment: Yes the huge potato was gone (needed to eat some gravel)

Comment: I can't remember if it was indigo

Comment: By "go with Tom Riddle", do you mean he gave that as his name? Why?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Since he's friends with Malfoy and Snape and he's in Slytherin, I believe he means that he joined Tom Riddle's side. ThehugePotatoIsBack - Was he in the same year as Snape/Malfoy in this story, or did you mean Draco Malfoy? Did you read this story in French?

Comment: @fuzzyBoots He was in the same year as Draco Malfoy. And I read it in English. Yes he joined Tom Riddles side